# CSS: percent min-height element nested within percent min-height element

Tags: css

I would like to make the html, body and wrapper elements all have a minimum height of 100% in order to cover the whole viewing window, but I have found that I can only make html obey this declaration.

```
html, body, #wrapper {
        min-height:100%;
        }

html {
        border: 2px red solid;
        }

body{
        border: 2px blue solid;
        }

#wrapper {
        border: 2px pink dotted;
        }
```

Create a simple html document with only a #wrapper div which can either have content in it or not. If a min-height of pixels is used, the elements obey it, but when I use percentages only html will work. Why is this?

Comment: Sorry, but would you mind making a more concise writing of your question (with related code)? I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what the problem is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will definitely help you...

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Comment: Thanks, this is good. I just wish I knew why I can't declare both the body and html elements to have a min-height of 100%

Answer (score 1):

Use `height` instead of `min-height`.

```
body,html{
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: But I want the wrapper/body/html to grow if the page expands beyond one screen height.

Comment: You can `#wrapper {min-height:100%}` but you must have `html, body {height:100%;}`.